# Create excel graph styles from lookup table

Tags: excel, vba, loops, excel-charts

I am trying to apply consistent graph styles based on a value in a field. I have 12 sets of RGB numbers and symbols, I want to apply these to the graph series with the same name.

I am nearly there, when I step into the code in the debugger it works but when I run the full macro the styling is just the default excel styles. Grateful for any ideas to complete the task in one hit?

Here is my code:

```
Sub GraphStyles()

' Appy consistent graph styles for LTC Design Elements
' Macro created by Dan Brenton 20200313

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strRef, strRange As String
    Dim iRow, iCount, iStart, iEnd, iCollection, Col, CountCol, Style, DesEl, Marker, Red, Green, Blue, DEdata As Integer
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If UCase(ws.Name) <> "TEMPLATE" And ws.Visible = True Then
            ws.Name = Replace(ws.Name, " ", "")
            ws.Name = Replace(ws.Name, "(Blank)", "NoGEOLCode")
            ws.Activate
            iRow = 62
            iStart = 62
            iCollection = 1
            Col = 1
            Style = 39
            DesEl = 15
            Marker = 16
            DEdata = 4

            'Select the existing chart, count and remove all series
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart14").Activate
            CountCol = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count

            For Col = 1 To CountCol

                ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete

            Next Col

            'Add series per design element

            Do While ws.Cells(iRow, 2) <> ""
                If ws.Cells(iRow, 4) <> ws.Cells(iRow + 1, 4) Then
                    iEnd = iRow
                    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart14").Activate
                    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(iCollection).Name = "=" & ws.Name & "!$D$" & iStart
                    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(iCollection).XValues = "=" & ws.Name & "!$N$" & iStart & ":$N$" & iEnd
                    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(iCollection).Values = "=" & ws.Name & "!$G$" & iStart & ":$G$" & iEnd

                        ' Apply design element styling (This works when stepped through the debugger but not when whole macro runs?!
                        Do While ws.Cells(Style, DesEl) <> ""

                        If ws.Cells(Style, DesEl) = ws.Cells(iStart, DEdata) Then
                        Red = Cells(Style, 18).Value
                        Green = Cells(Style, 19).Value
                        Blue = Cells(Style, 20)
                        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart14").Activate
                        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(iCollection).Select
                        With Selection
                            .MarkerStyle = Cells(Style, Marker)
                            .MarkerSize = 5
                            .Format.Line.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(Red, Green, Blue)
                            .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(Red, Green, Blue)
                            .Format.Fill.Solid
                        End With
                        End If
                        Style = Style + 1

                        Loop

                    iStart = iRow + 1
                    iCollection = iCollection + 1
                End If
                iRow = iRow + 1
            Loop


        End If
    Next

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```

Here is a preview of the data for context. Lookup table of styles in row 39 and raw data from row 62 these are linked by the data in column 4 and 15. 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

So I eventually figured it out and posting here for others reference.

```
    Sub GraphStyles()

' Appy consistent graph styles for LTC Design Elements
' Macro created by Dan Brenton 20200313

Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Application.EnableEvents = False
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual

    Dim wb As Workbook
    Dim ws As Worksheet
    Dim strRef, strRange As String
    Dim iRow, iCount, iStart, iEnd, iCollection, Col, CountCol, Style, DesEl, Marker, Red, Green, Blue, DEdata As Integer
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    For Each ws In wb.Worksheets
        If UCase(ws.Name) <> "TEMPLATE" And ws.Visible = True Then
            'Change ws names so as not to crash macro
            ws.Name = Replace(ws.Name, " ", "")
            ws.Name = Replace(ws.Name, "(Blank)", "NoGEOLCode")
            ws.Activate
            'Initialise variables
            iRow = 62
            iStart = 62
            iCollection = 1
            Col = 1
            Style = 39
            DesEl = 15
            Marker = 16
            DEdata = 4

            'Select the existing chart, count and remove all series
            ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart14").Activate
            CountCol = ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.Count
            For Col = 1 To CountCol
                ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(1).Delete
            Next Col

            'Add series per design element
            Do While ws.Cells(iRow, 2) <> ""
                If ws.Cells(iRow, 4) <> ws.Cells(iRow + 1, 4) Then
                    iEnd = iRow
                    ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart14").Activate
                    ActiveChart.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
                    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(iCollection).Name = "=" & ws.Name & "!$D$" & iStart
                    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(iCollection).XValues = "=" & ws.Name & "!$N$" & iStart & ":$N$" & iEnd
                    ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(iCollection).Values = "=" & ws.Name & "!$G$" & iStart & ":$G$" & iEnd

                        ' Loop through lookup table to find design element styling
                        Do While ws.Cells(Style, DesEl) <> ""
                        If ws.Cells(Style, DesEl) = ws.Cells(iStart, DEdata) Then

                        'Assign RGB numbers to variables based on relevant Design Element
                        Red = Cells(Style, 18).Value
                        Green = Cells(Style, 19).Value
                        Blue = Cells(Style, 20)
                        ActiveSheet.ChartObjects("Chart14").Activate
                        ActiveChart.FullSeriesCollection(iCollection).Select

                        'Format marker style, size and fill
                        With Selection
                            .MarkerStyle = Cells(Style, Marker)
                            .MarkerSize = 5
                            .Format.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(Red, Green, Blue)
                        End With

                        'Format marker border separately to avoid issues with code
                        With Selection.Format.Line
                            .Visible = msoFalse
                            .ForeColor.RGB = RGB(Red, Green, Blue)
                            .Transparency = 0
                        End With
                        End If
                        Style = Style + 1
                        Loop

                    'Reset style to top of lookup table
                    Style = 39
                    iStart = iRow + 1
                    iCollection = iCollection + 1
                End If
                iRow = iRow + 1
            Loop


        End If
    Next

Application.EnableEvents = True
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic

End Sub
```